# Identifying persistent clusters within a series of graphs

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, clustering, dimensionality-reduction, graphs

The task is to identify *persistent clusters*, i.e., groups of nodes that "persist" as clusters (tend to form a cluster) in a series of graphs.

This is how I approached the problem: I form a supergraph out of a series of input graphs, such that whenever an edge occurs again, its weight is increased by 1. Then, I apply Walktrap algorithm on the weighted supergraph (random walks are now dependent on weights), and the resulting clustering corresponds to persistent clusters.

Another idea is to go in embedding space (embedding available for input graphs in the series), and then apply similar idea: 1) form clustering on each input embedding, 2) form a supergraph comprising all the nodes, and where edges exist between all nodes forming a specific cluster (a clique is formed), and, as above, whenever an edge occurs again, its weight is increased by 1. In the end, I apply Walktraph algorithm.

However, although with pretty high running times, the above approaches do not yield satisfactory results (perhaps this is due to Walktrap, but a lot of non-persistent data tend to pollute the clusters). Do you have some other ideas on how to approach the problem?